# why do i get an error when i try to use my bot's "play" command?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, distube

my bot returns this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'options')
```

im trying to make a discord music bot. my code is here:

```
  execute: async ({ client, interaction }) => {
        let url = interaction.options.getString("url")
        client.distube.play(interaction.member.voice.channel, url, {
          member: interaction.member,
          textChannel: interaction.channel,
          interaction
        })
    }
}
```

it errors on the line where it says "interaction.options.getString"

Comment: This means `interaction` is undefined.

Comment: `interaction` is undefined like S. C. said, this is probably because you didn't pass the right arguments to the function. Your command handler file (like index.js) should have something like this: `command.execute({ client, interaction })`. Are you sure this is the case and it isn't `.execute(client, interaction)` without the object?